# Vue JS change submit button if errors

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Using Vuex I have a form that when the button is clicked (@click="loader(true)") sends to the loader mutation to change loading to true, which then sets a is-loading class with Bulma CSS to true ('is-loading' : $store.state.index.loading ).

I then receive errors from the server if the form is empty with errors.title, this works fine with the inputs but how do I then set the is-loading class to false if there are errors?

(the code snippet will not work if you run it)

```js
export const state = () => ({
  loading: false
});

export const mutations = {
  loader(state, value) {
    state.loading = value;
  }
 }
```

```html
<form @submit.prevent="postThis">

  <div class="field">
    <div class="control">
      <input class="input" :class="{ 'is-danger': errors.title }" type="text" id="title" placeholder="I have this idea to..." autofocus="" v-model="newTitle">

    </div>
    <p class="is-size-6 help is-danger" v-if="errors.title">
      {{ errors.title[0] }}
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <div class="control">

      <button @click="loader(true)" type="submit" :class="{'is-loading' : $store.state.index.loading }">
        Post
      </button>


    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<script>
  import {mapMutations,} from 'vuex';
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations({
      loader: 'index/loader'
    })
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You probably need to use an action in this case that toggles the value of `state.loading` to false depending on a response from the server.

Comment: Don't quote me on this but should be something along the lines of `this.$store.commit('loader', false)`. https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html

Comment: Oh. Wait. I misread that. Do some validation or a `try { } catch { }` in your `postThis` method. If you can expose that method to us can try and help further.

Comment: The postThis if using promises, you should be fine with the logic and the usage of mutations, state, actions. Usage of the mutation directly if you have business logic is bad. I would actually put the business logic within your action and then manage all the state using the commit. Commit(loading) then commit(failed) or commit(completedWithSuccess). Then you have only one method to call. After it is up to you tu use vuex properly ;)

Comment: Yes it makes sense to move the mutation into the action with commit('loader', true) but there's nothing wrong with using the mutation directly if you have no other need then to just change the state, this was clearly for example instead of putting the full action method

Answer (score 1):

The question is about using `...mapMutations`, but in case someone want to add business logic, `mapAction` and `mapState` would be recommended. I will explain how to make it work with `mapAction` and `mapState` since calling API might involve using business logic within your application. Otherwise, I would say, why do you even bother using VueX except for notifying other part of your application that you are loading ;). That being said, here's my answer.

Using the `...mapState` you have what you would be searching for, the `computed` reactivity of the state. This would happen especially during the invoke of the action. The action would then be changing, or what we call `commit` in VueX, the state (See doc: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html)

Let's take your code and change it into a module with a namespace and then use the module in your vue (This is what I would do if the application is big, otherwise the same can be achieved using the mutation or no VueX at all):

```
const LOADING_STATE = 'LOADING_STATE'
export default {
  namespaced: true, // Read the doc about that

  state: {
    loaded: false
  },

  mutations: {
    [LOADING_STATE]: function (state, isLoading) {
      state.loading = isLoading
    }
  },

  actions: {
    setLoading ({ commit }, isLoading) {
      commit(LOADING_STATE, isLoading)
    }
  }
}
```

For your **vue** file where you have your template and your actions. It would look like this:

```
<script>
  import { mapAction, mapState } from 'vuex'

  exports default {
     computed: {
        ...mapState({
          // Here you could even have the full computation for the CSS class.
          loading: state => state.loadingModule.loading,

          // Like this... or you could use the getters that VueX does (search in the documentation since it's out of the scope of your question)
          loadingCss: state => { return state.loadingModule.loading ? 'is-loading' : '' }
        })
      },
     methods: {
         // Usage of a namespace to avoid other modules in your VueX to have the same action.
         ...mapActions(['loadingModule/setLoading']),
     }
  }
</script>
```

And regarding your html template, you will be able to call the method `this['loadingModule/setLoading'](true)` or `false` and then the property that you can react to will be "loading".

While using promises, during your `post` or `get` *or* any other HTTP rest call, don't forget the context. If you're using Axios, after registering it in your VueJs context, I would do

```
this.$http.get('/my/api')
   .then(response => { 
      // ... some code and also set state to ok ... 
   })
   .catch(e => { 
      // set state to not loading anymore and open an alert 
   })
```

Let's complete your code now considering you're doing your HTTP(S) call somewhere.

```
<form @submit.prevent="postThis">

  <div class="field">
    <div class="control">
      <!-- Here I would then use a computed property for that class (error). I would even put the a template or a v-if on a div in order to show or not all those html elements. That's you're choice and I doubt this is your final code ;) -->
      <input class="input" :class="{ 'is-danger': errors.title }" type="text" id="title" placeholder="I have this idea to..." autofocus="" v-model="newTitle">
    </div>

    <p class="is-size-6 help is-danger" v-if="errors.title">
      {{ errors.title[0] }}
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <div class="control">
      <button @click="['loadingModule/setLoading'](true)" type="submit" :class="{'is-loading' : loading }">
        Post
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no need to have locally only needed state (loading) in global state (Vuex). So, typical usage looks like this:

```
<template>
  <form>
    <div class="field">
      <div class="control">
        <input
          class="input" :class="{ 'is-danger': errors.title }"
          type="text"
          id="title"
          placeholder="I have this idea to..."
          autofocus=""
          v-model="newTitle"
        >
      </div>
      <p class="is-size-6 help is-danger" v-if="errors.title">
        {{ errors.title[0] }}
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <div class="control">
        <button
          @click="postForm"
          :class="{'is-loading': isLoading }"
        >
          Post
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  ...
  data () {
    return {
      ...
      newTitle: '',
      isLoading: false,
      response: null
    }
  },

  methods: {
    async postForm () {
      try {
        this.isLoading = true // first, change state to true
        const { data } = await axios.post('someurl', { title: this.newTitle }) // then wait for some async call
        this.response = data // save the response
      } catch(err) {
        // if error, process it here
      } finally {
        this.isLoading = false // but always change state back to false
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Look to mdn documentation for try ... catch and async / await

Comment: Make another question with your actual code, this is an unreadable mess.

Answer (score -1):

if you using vuex like this. I guess you misunderstood vuex. Because you can use for local variable and you can check api result. if you want seperate api request, you have to mapAction in methods and mapGetters in Computed

Comment: You don’t have to map anything you can directly call mutations or state directly, map is a spread operator that you use when you have more than one action or getters, maybe you misunderstand how Vuex is flexible

Comment: https://vuex.vuejs.org/ there is vuex lifecyle https://vuex.vuejs.org/vuex.png

if you check you will understand what is doing action and mutation